# Nitro / Docker: containers missing

Tags: nitro, docker

Posting this as a problem and then answering it in case it helps someone else.

The sequence of events:

1. I had 3 sites running under Craft Nitro 2 and Docker 3.x
2. I became aware that Docker had moved to version 4.x and so downloaded and installed it
3. I sandboxed my Docker 3 and all seemed to be fine under Docker 4, and carried on working for some days
4. I decided to do some housekeeping and deleted my sandboxed Docker 3
5. Now Docker 4 would not see any containers at all and was stuck on “Docker Engine waiting…”
6. On the command line I could see via `nitro context` that my 3 sites were still known, at least in the hosts file
7. After thrashing around with Docker restart and **Clean / Purge data** I was none the wiser…

Answer (score 3):

Turns out all I needed to do was `nitro init`, which:

- Recreated the Nitro proxy and myql containers
- Recreated containers for my 3 sites

What had gone was all the databases, but I'm guessing that's only because I was dumb enough to **Clean / Purge data**. In my case that's OK as I can reinstate from somewhere else.

Long story short, if your Docker containers go missing, try `nitro init` *first!*